# What is the difference b/w Stack Pointer and W-Z Registers found in 8085?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessors, 8085

I am bit confused with the functionality of Stack Pointer and W-Z Registers present in 8085 microprocessor.A stack pointer is used to store the address during a interrupt call which further load into the programme counter to continue execution of programme,but as i have read from book the W-Z also utilised for same functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are two completely different things - the stack pointer is found on most CPUs and points to the current top of stack - for an interrupt or subroutine call it may be used to preserve data on the stack, and it may also be used for general purpose push/pop operations. It is visible to the programmer and may be modified explicitly or implicitly.

The W and Z registers are internal temporary registers which are not visible to the programmer and which are used internally during certain arithmetic operations. These are specific to the 8080 family and derivatives.

See [this page](http://www.zseries.in/embedded%20lab/8085%20microprocessor/architecture%20of%208085.php#.VcmkGHiX-iA) for more details and some nice diagrams and explanations.